# Copy files from android device to windows 7 laptop using windows command

Tags: windows

I connect my android phone to my laptop.  I see computer\gt-19100 in windows explorer for the phone.  I wish to run a dos command to copy photos from the android over to a temp directory on my laptop.

I try

```
C:\Users\Me>copy Computer\GT-I9100\Phone\DCIM\Camera\20130702_083215.jpg C:\temp
```

I get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: can you enabled mass storage option in android device

Answer (score 2):

You'll need Android Debug bridge to do that.

[You'll find a tutorial for that here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=694250).